# IIS - Forwarding requests to a folder to another port

Tags: iis-7, glassfish

#### Context

I currently installed Glassfish 3 in a server that currently holds ASP and PHP inside Internet Information Server 7 so we can start moving to a new system architecture (the information system is being remade). Obviously, Glassfish uses another port and without too much configuration (all I had to do is to install it) it worked. If I write www.domain.com:8080, the person will be redirected to the Glassfish server.

#### Issue

Obviously I don't want the person to write the port! I also believe it might also hold some security issues.

#### Requirement

I need the server to take an address of the form www.domain.com/gf or new.domain.com or something alike, and when it receives such a request, "redirect" (masking the URL) the user to the Glassfish website (www.domain.com:8080).

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you need something like the Apache Tomcat connector for iis dont let the name fool you it also works for glassfish

between this http://www.codefactorycr.com/glassfish-behind-apache.html (Yes i know it is for mod_JK but the workers.properties file is very similar for the isapi filter)
and https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=218270157

you should have a good start getting it working

Comment: Well, I did everything there, but I can't get to enter using either the port (website:8009) or the alias (which I think I did the latter wrong anyways) outside the server, much like my prior attempts. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: If you are saying you can't reach them outside the server the windows firewall may be blocking the traffic. Either make sure the proper exceptions are in place or try temporarily disabling the firewall

Comment: After thinking a little more another solution would be a reverse proxy using Application Request Routing and URL Rewrite in IIS7 you will need to install the modules from www.iis.net.  here is a tutorial to get you started if you wish to give this a try.  http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: I'm sorry I took so long to respond, I've been quite busy lately and haven't been able to do anything else. I tried doing what you suggested me at first again using another website, and now I get a 500 error when calling GetFilterVersion from the ISAPI. What might cause it?

Comment: Also today I tried using the URL rewrite and all I got was a 404 error...

Comment: After struggling a bit with the rewriter I did it, thank you!